# Alert View Equivalent in Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, view, uialertview, alert, cocos2d-x

I've looked all over the web but can't seem to find anything. I've tried CCMessageBox, but that doesn't provide any buttons. Will I just have to make my own?

Comment: There is nothing equivalent to AlertView in cocos2d-x but you may like to see this and do it yourself

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1944

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To develop a game I am using cocos2d-x and I think there is no build-in alert view right now. You have to do it yourself.